# Is Magic Weapon associated with a weapon or with the hero?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

The Wizard’s [Magic Weapon](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/magic-weapon) skill description reads:

> Imbue your weapon with magical energy, granting it 10% increased damage. Lasts 5 minutes.

What does it mean, imbue the **weapon**? If I switch weapons, do I lose the enchantment? And if I cast the spell and then give my weapon to another player, does that player get the benefit of the enchantment? Or is it just a fancy way of writing “+10% damage for 5 minutes”?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just a fancy way of saying "+10% damage for 5 minutes".

Fundamentally, you're looking at the skill wrong - it's not "imbue Target: Weapon", it's "imbue **your** weapon". If you give it to someone else (soulbound weapons notwithstanding), it's not *your* weapon, anymore, and presumably you have a *new* weapon.

Furthermore, since *all* skills with damage scale off... weapon damage, there is not even an issue of "But I don't use my weapon for X, do I still get the bonus?". The bonus works with all abilities (and includes the runed versions of magic weapon too. Every spell gets lifesteal? Why not!)

**You** get the bonus. Always. It's a self-buff, and it vanishes when you change your weapon. This also applies to your offhand (should you cast MW on a 1-hander, you lose your MW bonus when you swap offhands).

Comment: So it doesn't only affect melee but also all spells?

Comment: @ThiefMaster Correct.