# How does Magic Weapon (and its runed varieties) interact with other skills?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Magic Weapon associated with a weapon or with the hero?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66157/is-magic-weapon-associated-with-a-weapon-or-with-the-hero)

The Wizard’s [Magic Weapon](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/magic-weapon) skill increases the damage of the Wizard’s weapon. Does this also increase the damage of all other skills, as they rely on the weapon’s damage, or does it only affect regular attacks?

In addition, Magic Weapon’s runes add on-hit effects. When do these apply? For instance, the Force Weapon rune adds a chance for a knockback effect. Does that mean a Wizard has a chance to cause knockback when casting [Disintegrate](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/disintegrate), when under that enchantment?

Comment: Closing as duplicate. I answered this in my answer on your first question. Just edited my 3rd paragraph to make that more clear.

Comment: @Raven thinking about it some more and I think I agree :) though I'd appreciate if you could address runes in that other answer.